# Why didFinishWith delegate method is called automatically while using MFMailComposeViewController in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to present `MFMailComposeViewController` to send email but the problem is that `MFMailComposeViewController` pop is dismissed automatically as soon as it presents. The `didFinishWith` delegate method is called automatically just after present the `MFMailComposeViewController`, I don't know why it's happening.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import MessageUI
class MyProfileViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let senderMail = ["xyz@gmail.com"]
        let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
        guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else{
            CommonUtils.showToast(message: "Mail services are not available")
            return
        }
        mailComposer.setToRecipients(senderMail)
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
        self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    
    switch (result){
    case MFMailComposeResult.cancelled:
        print("Mail cancelled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResult.saved:
        print("Mail saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResult.sent:
        print("Mail sent");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResult.failed:
        print("Mail sent failure: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    // Close the Mail Interface
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Are you testing it on a device or a simulator?

Comment: simulator, problem resolved as in simulator it's not working but in device it's working

Comment: the simulator needs to have a mail account set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working in real device but not in simulator